# Unable to use debounceTime on ion-button click event

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4, subject, debouncing

Currently I am having an ion-button with click event which calls a method.

`<ion-button expand="full" color="primary" (click)="sendMsg()">Tap</ion-button>`

sendMsg method contains the statements to push the objects to an array and opens modal on some condition.

`sendMsg = () =>{
// statements to push an objects to an array(this is an array displays on chat page);
this.openModal();
}`

`async openModal() {
      const myModal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: {
        firstAction: this.firstAction,
        secondAction: this.secondAction,
        thirdAction: this.thirdAction
      },
      cssClass: 'modal-css',
      backdropDismiss: false
    });`

It's a chat page where we get the messages on click of TAP button and while tapping in between we show an ion modal . The issue here is when we tap super fast and modal comes up in one of the click event and since we are clicking fast I could see the messages displaying which are suppose to display after the modal comes up..

To avoid this , I thought of adding debounceTime which can have some time delay and considers the latest click event and this was working in normal angular world.

I have followed https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-custom-debounce-click-directive-in-angular but it didn't work under ionic..

Any thoughts are really appreciated..

Comment: You need to put the relevant `ts` code also.

Answer (score 0):

use a subject as event emitting source and control the click rate from there

```
const openModalAction=new Subject()
sendMsg = () =>{
// statements to push an objects to an array(this is an array displays on chat page);
openModalAction.next()
}

const openModal=defer(()=>from(this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: {
        firstAction: this.firstAction,
        secondAction: this.secondAction,
        thirdAction: this.thirdAction
      },
      cssClass: 'modal-css',
      backdropDismiss: false
    })))

const openModalAction.pipe(dounceTime(1000),switchMap(_=>openModal)
```